# How to use a datafile, that was multiple imputed in SPSS, in R?

Tags: r, spss, multiple-imputation

I've got a pooled SPSS datafile that has been imputed in SPSS with multiple imputation algorithm. Now, in order to render diagrams, I would like to import that pooled SPSS datafile in R. I know how to import it, so can I just import it into R and start analyzing and rendering or will I have to do some precautions? I mean, does R have to know that it is a imputed file or doesn't that matter? (I don't need to know the differences between original data and imputed data, I just want to render the images based on the imputed data).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a pooled dataset created by SPSS via multiple imputation. What is produced is a large dataset with the original incomplete data, plus some number (5, by default) of completed datasets where imputations have been made to create datasets with no missing data (if appropriate specifications were made in doing the imputations). The datasets are identified within the one big dataset by a variable named Imputation_.

The completed datasets would be analyzed separately and particular results from the analyses of completed datasets would then be pooled, using Rubin's rules. There is no single pooled set of data. If you want to render images based on the imputed data, you'd need to create images for each set of imputed data, as there is no one set of pooled data with which to work.